# iOS download font error when have weak network such as flight-mode

Tags: ios, fonts

From iOS6 we can dynamic download font from Apple. I downloaded the example code from [DownloadFont Demo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DownloadFont/Listings/DownloadFont_ViewController_m.html). And I found something weird.

Firstly, I using a good wifi network, downloaded all the font in the list and show the correct font word successfully.

Secondly, I shut down the network like flight-mode. Return the project.

Thirdly, selected one font such as "DFWaWaSC-W5", I found the log in the console of XCode that

```
2014-03-10 17:14:36.840 DownloadFont[2946:1807] still couldn't match <CTFontDescriptor:    0x16547750>{attributes = <CFBasicHash 0x165588e0 [0x3a073ae0]>{type = mutable dict, count = 1,
entries =>
1 : <CFString 0x3a0efd24 [0x3a073ae0]>{contents = "NSFontNameAttribute"} = <CFString 0x9bfbc [0x3a073ae0]>{contents = "DFWaWaSC-W5"}
}
>}
```

And the text didn't use the `"DFWaWaSC-W5"` font but system font. Then select any other font which I had downloaded before such as `"STLibian-SC-Regular"`, it show the correct font. After that I reselect the font `"DFWaWaSC-W5"` which didn't show correctly, I got the correct font as `"DFWaWaSC-W5"`.

I don't know why. Did anybody got the same weird situation？ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The downloading of font(CTFontDescriptorMatchFontDescriptorsWithProgressHandler) seems to work only when WIFI Internet connection is available.